# Set value of ng-content with pure javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code from some CMS:

```
<esw-input _ngcontent-ysg-c21="" class="address-form__middleName ng-touched ng-pristine" type="text" _nghost-ysg-c16="" maxlength="60"><input _ngcontent-ysg-c16="" class="textInput ng-pristine ng-touched" triggers="manual" id="middleName" type="text" placeholder="Отчество" required="" maxlength="60"><!----><div _ngcontent-ysg-c16="" class="error"><esw-field-validation _ngcontent-ysg-c16="">Пожалуйста, введите ваш отчество
</esw-field-validation></div></esw-input>
```

How to set value of this field with javascript or jquery? I try following

```
var element = $("#middleName");
element.val(MiddleName).trigger('blur');
```

With this code I see new value, but field reported as invalid(empty) and not possible to submit form. Some CMS used, and blocks me to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with pure JS.
UPD with focus and blur methods

```js
// Shortcut
const s = document.getElementById("middleName");

// Focus field
s.focus();
// Add value
s.value = "Джонович";
// Set value attribute to input tag
s.setAttribute("value", "Джонович");
// blur field
s.blur();
```

```html
<esw-input _ngcontent-ysg-c21="" class="address-form__middleName ng-touched ng-pristine" type="text" _nghost-ysg-c16="" maxlength="60">
<input _ngcontent-ysg-c16="" class="textInput ng-pristine ng-touched" triggers="manual" id="middleName" type="text" placeholder="Отчество" required="" maxlength="60">
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-ysg-c16="" class="error">
<esw-field-validation _ngcontent-ysg-c16="">Пожалуйста, введите ваш<b style="color:red">e</b> отчество</esw-field-validation></div></esw-input>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Value changed, but form is not valid like this value is empty

Comment: The same. I see changed value, but still validation error

Comment: Then it is something about validation code, which isn't presented here... It could be the lack of updating values from input by validator after you do insert operation

Comment: Same. I have also try input event, keydown, change. Nothing helps. I haven't access to validation method.

Comment: Well then idk, because there could be many details why this is happening and we need to understand how validator works. Maybe while you typing in the field, CMS script do copy each letter to some internal function...

Comment: Site provides stronger protection, so answer not helps. But it correct in many situations, so I accept it